# Is too much of global declaration in android activity or fragment bad? Will it affect performance of the screen loading?

Tags: android

I would like to know if global declarations of too many variables bad in android activity class or fragment class.
Would it affect performance?

Comment: could you show some sample code please? not the full thing, just a sample so that your question will be more clear

Comment: Proper scoping of variables is necessary both for memory management and cleaner code. As Marcin told, performance is the last thing to worry about, its all about your coding technique which will pay off at the end. Just because few global variables dont effect performance, pushing them to global is bad practice and must be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if global declarations of too many variables bad in android activity class or fragment class

No, it the same case as with any other java class. Usually the less the better, for the sake of code maintenance, testability and simply readability. Too many global members may simply indicate that your code is messy and not isolated properly.

And how many is too many? If you got 10, even 20 - that'd be rather ok. But if you count 100, then I'd say there is definitely something wrong with the code.

> Would it affect performance

Last thing to worry about here.

Comment: Thanks. You answered my question.